# Flatten observable array in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I'm using Firebase in my Angular2 app to retrieve data from my database. What's the easiest was of returning an array of unique values in the nested *tags* list? I.e. in my example I want to return `["Sport", "Adventure", "Music"]` where the 2nd *"Adventure"* is omitted.

```
{
"images": {
    "image1": {
        "path": "path",
        "date": 43534532123,
        "tags": {
           0: "Sport",
           1: "Adventure"
        }
    },
    "image2": {
        "path": "path",
        "date": 43534532123,
        "tags": {
           0: "Music",
           1: "Adventure"
        }
     }            

 }
```

I tried this approach but it seems to split the elements from the first image only

```
 return this.af.database.list('/photos/user')
      .map(photos => photos.map(photo => photo.tags))
      .concatAll()
      .distinct()
```

However, this approach yields the correct output but as a separate stream of the unique tags instead of as one array

```
 return this.af.database.list('/photos/user')
      .map(photos => photos.map(photo => photo.tags))
      .mergeAll()
      .mergeAll()
      .distinct()
```

Comment: My bad, it should have been image1 and image2

Comment: To be honest you probably don't even need any special observable magic for this...your `map` function can just take the object from the API and reduce it into that array. All the logic for it can go inside the `map` callback. Observable themselves operators are moreso for *manipulating the stream of data, not the data in the stream*. Subtle difference, but important. That's why I think it's within the callback of `map` that you can simply process the data. You don't need `distinct` emissions, you need the actual data to change.

Comment: Please, to improve the quality of the question, clarify the structure of the observable `this.af.database.list('/photos/user')`. Define the type and members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I assumed in the original answer that it was a stream with the individual items. Later the OP clarified it is a stream of a list of *photos*. In this case we use `Array#reduce` instead of `Observable#reduce`.

```
return this.af.database.list('/photos/user')
  .map(photos => photos.map(photo => photo.tags)
      .reduce((allTags, current) => {
           return allTags.concat(
               current.filter(item => allTags.indexOf(item) === -1))
      }, []))
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

`distinct` over an observable returns unique individual values in an stream, but is not the operator we want here. It's is possible to produce a sequence with all the tags, each one as a separate value, but then we would need to regroup them again.

We can use instead `reduce`, quite similar to the Array counterpart. It takes an initial value (`[]`) and accumulates the others. We built a list with the individual values on each iteration. After the reduce we have an array of unique tags.

Notice that `.list()` should complete the observable for it to work.

```
return this.af.database.list('/photos/user')
      .map(photos => photos.map(photo => photo.tags))
      .reduce((allTags, current) => {
           return allTags.concat(
               current.filter(item => allTags.indexOf(item) === -1))
      }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like a good solution but unfortunately it doesn't work. 1) I get an error that **Property includes' does not exist on type 'any[]**. Also, when I subscribe to the result I don't get any output. How should I ensure that the .list() is complete first in order for this to work?

Comment: re: `includes`, it's from ES2016, add `lib:["es2016"]` to `tsconfig.json`. You might need a polyfill. I guess I'll change the answer to use indexOf()

Comment: I see, as for the .list() most be completed should I call something like take(x) before the .map() is called?

Comment: Something doesn't look right. `map(photos => ` receive what object? I would expect an array of `/user`.

Comment: I changed it for this example to make it easier, but it's actually the specific fotos for that user id so it would look like: /photos/userid

Comment: Hum, then it's another thing. From my post, remove one ) from `photo.tags))`, then append to `[])`. Then tell me if it works.